# parse.com получить значение

Tags: ios, swift, parse.com

Продолжаю изучать parse.com. Подскажите, как можно вытащить конкретное значение поля? Например есть функция:

```
    let object = PFQuery(className: "MapObject")
    object.whereKey("User", equalTo: "Вася")
    object.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) in
      print (objects)
    }
```

Она вытаскивает весь объект по пользователю Васе. Как мне достать значение конкретного поля? Ну например поля "Room"- номер квартиры. Если ткнете в мануал с примерами по работе на свифт с parse.com на русском, буду благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Получить данные можно в цикле:

```
      for object in objects! {
        let result = object["Room"] as! Int
      }
```